# How Can I Get The Value Of The Components That I Created Programmatically?

Tags: android

I fetch my data from my web server using JSON string (see below)

```
{"identification":[{"question":"Who created the C programming language?","answers":"Dennis Ritchie","subject":"1","points":"1","question-id":"1"},{"question":"What company created Visual Basic?","answers":"Microsoft","subject":"1","points":"1","question-id":"2"}],"multiplechoice":[{"question":"Which of the following programming languages are not Object Oriented?","answers":"C","choices":["Java","Visual Basic"],"subject":"1","points":"1","question-id":"3"},{"question":"The person who is responsible for the creation of Facebook?","answers":"Mark Zuckerberg","choices":["Steve Jobs","Bill Gates","Larry Page"],"subject":"1","points":"1","question-id":"4"}]}
```

Using that data I created a dynamic components for e.g. some question have 3 choices hence 3 radio buttons some have 5 choices which is 5 radio buttons etc.

Now the main problem is I really don't have any idea on how to get the reference of the components that I created programmatically, I know how use findViewById when using XML but this time there are no XML file used except for the parent layouts.

I'm planning on retrieving and parsing all the value of the components that I created back into JSON string. (which I have an idea on how to do and not the main problem of this question)

The code below is the one who is responsible for dynamically creating components:

```
if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonObj.toString().trim());

                Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();

                Log.d("TEST: ", "WORKING> " + "ENABLED");

                JSONArray temp_json_arr = null;

                JSONObject temp_json_obj = null;

                String temp_string = "";

                int question_number = 1;

                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.test_layout);

                while( keys.hasNext() ){

                    String key = (String)keys.next();
                    Log.d("TEST: ", "KEYS> " + key);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    temp_json_arr = jsonObj.getJSONArray(key);

                    // looping through All Questions
                    for (int i = 0; i < temp_json_arr.length(); i++) {

                        Log.d("TEST: ", "EXECUTE> before if condition");

                        JSONObject q = temp_json_arr.getJSONObject(i);

                        if( key.equals("identification") ) {

                            Log.d("TEST: ", "EXECUTE> START");

                            int element_ctr = 0;

                            TextView[] question_textview = new TextView[10];

                            TextView[] label_textview = new TextView[10];

                            EditText[] answer_edittext = new EditText[10];

                            TextView[] seperator_textview = new TextView[10];

                            //question node
                            question_textview[element_ctr] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

                            question_textview[element_ctr].setText(question_number+". "+q.getString("question"));

                            question_textview[element_ctr].setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.GlobalTextView);

                            //question_textview[element_ctr].

                            ll.addView(question_textview[element_ctr]);

                            //label node
                            label_textview[element_ctr] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

                            label_textview[element_ctr].setText("Answer:");

                            label_textview[element_ctr].setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.GlobalTextView);

                            ll.addView(label_textview[element_ctr]);

                            //answer node
                            answer_edittext[element_ctr] = new EditText(getApplicationContext());

                            answer_edittext[element_ctr].setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.GlobalTextView);

                            ll.addView(answer_edittext[element_ctr]);

                            if(i!=temp_json_arr.length()-1) {

                                //seperator
                                seperator_textview[element_ctr] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

                                seperator_textview[element_ctr].setText("--------------------------------------------------");

                                ll.addView(seperator_textview[element_ctr]);

                                Log.d("TEST: ", "EXECUTE> END");

                            }

                        }

                        if( key.equals("multiplechoice") ) {

                            Log.d("TEST: ", "EXECUTE> START");

                            int element_ctr = 0;

                            TextView[] question_textview = new TextView[10];

                            TextView[] label_textview = new TextView[10];

                            RadioButton[] answer_radiobutton = new RadioButton[10];

                            TextView[] seperator_textview = new TextView[10];

                            //question node
                            question_textview[element_ctr] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

                            question_textview[element_ctr].setText(question_number+". "+q.getString("question"));

                            question_textview[element_ctr].setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.GlobalTextView);

                            ll.addView(question_textview[element_ctr]);

                            //label node
                            label_textview[element_ctr] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

                            label_textview[element_ctr].setText("Answer:");

                            label_textview[element_ctr].setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.GlobalTextView);

                            ll.addView(label_textview[element_ctr]);

                            //choices node
                            JSONArray temp_json_arr2 = null;

                            temp_json_arr2 = q.getJSONArray("choices");

                            temp_string = q.getString("answers");

                            temp_json_arr2.put(temp_string);

                            Random rnd = new Random();
                            for (int k = temp_json_arr2.length() - 1; k >= 0; k--)
                            {
                              int j = rnd.nextInt(k + 1);
                              // Simple swap
                              Object object = temp_json_arr2.get(j);
                              temp_json_arr2.put(j, temp_json_arr2.get(k));
                              temp_json_arr2.put(k, object);
                            }

                            Log.d("TEST: ", "TRAP> START");

                            int group_ctr = 0;

                            RadioButton[] choices_radiobutton = new RadioButton[10];
                            RadioGroup[] choices_radiogroup = new RadioGroup[10]; //create the RadioGroup
                            choices_radiogroup[group_ctr] = new RadioGroup(getApplicationContext());
                            choices_radiogroup[group_ctr].setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);

                            Log.d("TEST: ", "TRAP> END");


                            for (int t = 0; t < temp_json_arr2.length(); t++) {

                                choices_radiobutton[t]  = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
                                choices_radiobutton[t].setText(temp_json_arr2.getString(t));
                                choices_radiobutton[t].setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.GlobalTextView);
                                choices_radiogroup[group_ctr].addView(choices_radiobutton[t]); //the RadioButtons are added to the radioGroup instead of the layout

                            }

                            ll.addView(choices_radiogroup[group_ctr]);//you add the whole RadioGroup to the layout

                            group_ctr++;

                            if(i!=temp_json_arr.length()-1) {

                                //seperator
                                seperator_textview[element_ctr] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

                                seperator_textview[element_ctr].setText("--------------------------------------------------");

                                ll.addView(seperator_textview[element_ctr]);

                                Log.d("TEST: ", "EXECUTE> END");

                            }

                        }

                        if( key.equals("truefalse") ) {

                            //Log.d("TEST: ", "hi iam true or false");

                        }

                        question_number++;

                    }//end for

                }//end while
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
```

I'm sorry for codes, I just started creating android app and I'm still trying to get a hang with basic stuffs before jumping into complicated code structures, I just want to solve the problem I'm having right now before proceeding with other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution would be to set ID for the Views/components when you create them in the code.

Use this method.

```
someView.setId(int);
```

The int must be positive. (Any number)

Once you set the ID, you can refer it in the code elsewhere.

**Example**

```
TextView1.setId(10);

TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(10);
```

Comment: Can you at least show me how can I refer it using the code above? Is it R.id.23 if 23 is the number of the component?

Answer (score 0):

Though it may seems complicated at the start may help you improve on further requirement.

It is better to create a DataStructure (custom class) to de-serialize this json to Object (refer GSON library) then bind it to the UI. And then if UI is updated assign the updated values to Object and send back to server (refer Retrofit library for easy REST operations)

Comment: I don't really know what you are talking about.